# XPath in Firebug console with a space in content

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I am trying to use an XPath in the Firebug console to get a `<span>` element's text content.
The actual `<span>` tag content is 'first name' with a space within as shown below:

```
<span class="vl-cell e-listview-container-mail-Col5" iscell="1">first name</span>
```

When I enter the XPath below into Firebug's command line

```js
$x("//div[@id='tble-listview-container-mail']/div[2]/span[4]")[0].innerHTML
```

I get the following output:

```js
"first&nbsp;name"   // getting a &nbsp; for the space within the string 'first name'.
```

When I want to get the element containing this text like

```js
$x("//div[@id='tble-listview-container-mail']/div[2]/span[text()='first name']")
```

I get this as output:

```js
[]  // output is returned as empty
```

Can someone tell how I can get the element if the inner text has a space within it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `&nbsp;` in the output is an indication that you have a non-breaking space between the two words and **not** a normal space.

Therefore the output array is empty when you search for the containing text `first name` (with normal space). You need to search for `first name` (with non-breaking space) instead. I.e. the function call then looks like this:

```js
$x("//div[@id='tble-listview-container-mail']/div[2]/span[text()='first name']")
```

*Note: You can display HTML entities using their name or Unicode representation via the [HTML panel options 'Show Entities As Names' and 'Show Entities As Unicode'](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu).*

Comment: I have deleted my answer since I think it does not contribute a helpful solution, thanks for pointing it out.